# html page is stopping on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using the code below and it's slowing down and stopping at a different div.

```
   $("#btn").click(function() {
                    $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: $("#footer_1").offset().top
                    },2000);
                });
```

Even if I use this code:

```
$("#btn").click(function() {
                $('html, body').animate({
                    scrollTop: $("#footer_1").offset().top
                });
            });
```

It goes to the div but there's an offset and when I click "btn" again then it goes to the complete div .

How can I make it work with a smooth scroll?

Comment: Keep in mind that you are using `+50`, which would explain the offset if I'm understanding you correctly.

Comment: @NieDzejkob I've removed it avoid confusion. But i still have the same issue.

Comment: Have you tried console.log($("#footer_1").offset().top); to see if the value looks correct? Can you provide your html as well perhaps?

Comment: Keep in mind that `The vertical scroll position is the same as the number of pixels that are hidden from view above the scrollable area.`, which might be influenced by margins, sticky navbars, etc.

Comment: @SebBrown Interesting! It throws out 2 values : the 1st time it is 5037 and if I click on the same button again then I get 7207 . Btw, the value 5037 only appears when I reload the page otherwise it's 7207.

Comment: Try to create a [mcve], otherwise we just can't help.